# Change format of long variable?

Tags: java, string, long-integer, type-conversion

Hello every one please give me suggestions, I'm trying to change string to long variable  like this but fail please let me know how to change :

I have a variable of long type

```
x = 1411833674288;
```

I'm converting this to string the it shows like this `1.411833674288E12`

How can I change it back to `1411833674288`

**Thanks**

Comment: Please provide us a code how you do that ?

Comment: this the code i am declaing variable x and convert it into string then i want back same as it is

Comment: Edit your question and add your code. You're obviously doing something wrong, and we're trying to help you fix that. It's impossible to help without seeing what you are doing.

Answer (score 3):

Simply do like this:

**Long to String**

```
long x=1411833674288L; 

String longToString = Long.toString(x);//or you can use String.valueOf(x);
```

**String back to Long**

```
long y = Long.parseLong(longToString);
```

**Edited**

note that this value exceed the limit of long data type so you should use long within its range or put L or l at the end of the value as @Rustum said in the comment

Comment: `long x=1411833674288;` this will give compile time error. put `l` or `L` at the end of number to indicate that it is long type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
String.valueOf(valueLong);
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this :**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

       long  longVal=1411833674288l;
       String stringVal=Long.toString(longVal);
       System.out.println("longVal = "+longVal);
       System.out.println("stringVal = "+stringVal);
       System.out.println("back to longVal = "+Long.parseLong(stringVal));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have three options:

```
String y = String.valueof(x);
```

```
String y = x.toString();
```

```
String y = x + ""; //This is not very clear but it does work.
```

If you want to parse to a long:

```
Long d = Long.parseLong(String);
```